# Generic method with specified types

Tags: c#, generics

Can I do something like this:

```
public void Foo<T>(int param) where T: MYCLASS1, MYCLASS2
```

To specify that T will only be  MYCLASS1 or MYCLASS2 instance?

Thank you..

Comment: As others have stated: no. If you elaborate on what the type is used for in the function, perhaps you'll get a better way to go about doing this.

Comment: You are right.. I think I have to use polymorphism.. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, when you specify generic type constraints, the generic type argument must satisfy *all* the constraints, not just one of them. The code you wrote means that `T` must inherit both `MYCLASS1` and `MYCLASS2`, which is not possible since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance. The generic type constraints can be a combination of:

- a base class (only one allowed)
- one or several interfaces
- the `new()` constraint (i.e. the type must have a parameterless constructor)
- either `struct` or `class` (but not both, since a type can't be a value type *and* a reference type)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

While adding constraints on a generic type you can list only one class and others have to be interfaces.

This is a valid constraint -

```
public void Foo<T>(int param) where T: MyClass1, IInterface1, IInterface2
```

But not this

```
public void Foo<T>(int param) where T: MyClass1, MyClass2
```

This is logical, because when you declare a variable of type Foo such as `Foo<MyType>`, your `MyType` can derive from `MyClass1`, `IInterface1` and `MyInterface2` but it cannot derive from both `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`.

Answer (score 1):

No, generic constraints are always ANDed together. You will have to do a runtime check:

```
public void Foo<T>(int param) {
    if (typeof(T) != typeof(MyClass1) && typeof(T) != typeof(MyClass2))
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be MyClass1 or MyClass2");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354780/generic-method-with-specified-types/5354814#5354814) points out, you cannot do this. What you can do however is this:

```
public void Foo<T>(int param) where T: IMyInterface
```

As long as you know that both `MYCLASS1` and `MYCLASS2` implement `IMyInterface`